# Javascript .map(...) with React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deep-copy

In my React code I have something like

```
{elements.map((element) => {
   return (
      <div>
           {renderDate(element.date)}
      </div>
   )
}})}
```

where

```
const renderDate = (date: string) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span className="date">
                {date}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I look at the UI, I see that all the elements on the page have the same date as the last date in the `elements` array. However I want to maintain each elements date and not have it been overwritten. Can anyone offer suggestion? Should I turn `.map(...)` into `.forEach(...)`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Updated.

Comment: you're missing `key` https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: adding the `key` is certainly best practice and can help with performance - but it won't cause this bug. Could you possibly make a demo of this problem on a site like codesandbox or codepen (etc) and link to it in your question so that we can take a look at your actual code and data?

Answer (score 0):

Without further details I can't say for sure, but it might just be syntax. I think you have an extra closing brace (`}`) on the last line. Try this:

```
{elements.map((element, i)=> (
  <div key={i} >
    {renderDate(element.date)}
  </div>
))}
```

As mentioned, you also need to add a `key` prop. If the `elements` array is not going to be updated, causing the component to re-render, a simple index `key` like above will work. Alternatively, if the dates are all unique you could use `<div key={element.date}>`, or another value which is unique to each item.